# JavaScript: match is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a javascript project right now, and getting an error that I wasn't expecting. When I try running:

*There are text inputs going into firstCheck and lastCheck

```
function firstCheck(FirstName){
    if(FirstName.value != null || (alphaNumCheck(FirstName))){
      return true;
    }
    valCheck = false;
    return false;
}

function lastCheck(LastName){
   if(LastName.value != null || (alphaNumCheck(FirstName))){
      return true;
   }
   valCheck = false;
   return false;
}


function alphaNumCheck(entry) {
   let regex = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
   if (entry != null && entry.match(regex)) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
```

I am getting an error that states: Uncaught TypeError: entry.match is not a function

I use the exact same code in another js file of mine and it works perfectly. Does anyone have an idea as to why it isn't working now?

Comment: You may want to change `entry != null` to `typeof entry === 'string'`

Comment: Does it make a difference now that I have added how it is called

Comment: Side note: In your own code you can obviously do whatever you want, but overwhelmingly, the convention in JavaScript is that function parameter names (and variable names, and function names for non-constructor functions) start with a lowercase letter. So `firstName` rather than `FirstName`. Initially-capped names are basically only used for constructor functions.

Comment: If the `alphaNumCheck` expects `entry` to be just a string which matches with that regex, using the suggested comparison makes more sense. This, however, doesn't change the fact that you are currently passing a non-string value to the function.

Comment: check the type of the entry variable, match() exists on strings not on other structures, you are passing a structure.

Comment: Side note: `lastCheck` uses `FirstName` in the `alphaNumCheck` instead of `LastName`.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing the *`HTMLInputElement` object* into `alphaNumCheck`. You want to pass its *value* in instead:

```
if(FirstName.value != null || (alphaNumCheck(FirstName.value))){
// Added .value here ---------------------------------^
```

Also note that `.value` on an `HTMLInputElement` (or other HTML elements with a `.value` property) will never be `null`, it's always a string. So there's no need for the `!= null` part of the above (and if there were, you already have it in `alphaNumCheck` anyway).

Comment: This fixed that problem, but now it's passing through as an undefined value? (FirstName = "Calista", entry = undefined)